# D3.js color with domain a set of colors and range a subset of colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm trying to create a color scale with domain a list of colors and range a "sublist" of colors.
Maybe is better to explain with an example. I would like a function such that `color("#00FF00")`, returns a different kind of green like for example **dark green**.
This is because i need to catalogue a list of items with some standard colors and a sublist with "subcolors"

Answer (score 0):

There are around 140 named colous you can use in css.  See for example https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hex.asp.  It includes things like "red", "yellow", "teal", "deepskyblue" and so on.  To select you could use a select tag and have option tags with text equal to the name and with backgroundColor also equal to the name.

Comment: jesus christ, i need to do it in a programmatically way, i can't map manually the items to a color...

Comment: Not sure what you mean - there are standard colors why not use them?  Should be enough for most things.  Anyway you can map manually, just create an object such as:
colors={"aliceblue":"#f0f8ff","antiquewhite":"#faebd7","aqua":"#00ffff","aquamarine":"#7fffd4","azure":"#f0ffff","beige":"#f5f5dc",.... etc
so you don't need a function as such.